# Cannot find namespace 'GameContext'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use the `useContext` hook in React with Typescript. I get an error saying `Cannot find namespace 'GameContext'.`

I've used this same syntax with regular .js but with Typescript it doesn't seem to work.

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const GameContext = createContext();

export const GameProvider = (props) => {
  const [game, setGame] = useState({});

  return (
    <GameContext.Provider value={[game, setGame]}>
      {props.children}
    </GameContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: can you post the detailed error message

Answer (score 1):

That particular error message is strange (a stack trace would help), but I can see right away that you haven't properly typed your context or provided an initial value.  The initial value is optional in JS but is required in TS.

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction, PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

// replace this with your actual type
type Game = {}

// tuple with the same types as the useState tuple
type GameContextValue = [ Game, Dispatch<SetStateAction<Game>> ]

// set an initial value with a game and setGame that fulfill the expected type
export const GameContext = createContext<GameContextValue>([
    {}, 
    () => console.error("attempted to use GameContext outside of a Provider")
]);

// need to set a type for props which includes children
export const GameProvider = (props: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  // need to declare the type for the state
  const [game, setGame] = useState<Game>({});

  return (
    <GameContext.Provider value={[game, setGame]}>
      {props.children}
    </GameContext.Provider>
  )
}

const Test = () => {
    // game and setGame get proper types
    const [game, setGame] = useContext(GameContext);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/AwQZnN)